# SQL - "No Unique Constraint Matching Given Keys" Despite Presence of Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm working on a project which involves implementing a simplified version of a school database. The 3 relevant tables are listed below:

```
create table classes(        --A given class
    class_code varchar(10) primary key
);

create table class_offerings(    --A particular instance of a class
    class_code varchar(10),
    class_name varchar(128) not null,
    semester_code integer,
    maximum_capacity integer check (maximum_capacity >= 0),
    teacher_name varchar(50) not null,    --heavily simplified
    primary key (class_code, semester_code),
    foreign key (class_code) references classes(class_code) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade
);

create table prerequisites(
    prereq varchar(10),
    class_code varchar(10),
    semester_code integer,
    primary key (class_code, semester_code),
    foreign key (class_code) references classes(class_code) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade,
    foreign key (semester_code) references class_offerings(semester_code) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade,
    foreign key (prereq) references classes(class_code) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

When I try and create "prerequisites," I'm given the message "ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table class_offerings." While it *is* true that I haven't applied the UNIQUE constraint to semester_code, it's part of the primary key, which to my understanding enforces a unique combination of all elements in the primary key. If I turn out to be wrong, I still don't want to have to apply UNIQUE to the semester_code, as multiple entries of the same semester_code should be allowed provided they don't share the same class_code. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign keys can also be made up of several columns:

```
foreign key (class_code, semester_code) 
     references class_offerings(semester_code,class_code) 
     on delete cascade on update cascade,
```

Personally however, I would avoid such a design. If possible I would introduce artificial IDs as auto-increment columns that always serve a primary keys. That way foreign keys always can be on the artificial ID column.

Natural keys are good and should be put as constraints to the db as well, I would just not build relationships on natural keys. However, this is my personal preference and there are arguments for having natural keys a primary keys as well: https://sqlstudies.com/2016/08/29/natural-vs-artificial-primary-keys/